# Locking a DB table and waiting for writing/reading it from a web application

Tags: java, mysql, concurrency, locks

I'm working on a web application using Spring (Java and JPA + Hibernate) and I was wondering if there is a way of **locking a MYSQL table** and then when another web service (or even another thread from the same application) tries to read or write the locked table **it waits for it to be unlocked**.

For example, imagine a use case (transaction) that needs to read a value and then increment it. There is a **concurrency problem**, because 2 or more threads at the same time are trying to read+write the same table.

Do I have to program it manually? Is that possible with java or using any of his libraries?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html

Comment: "or example, imagine a use case (transaction) that needs to read a value and then increment it." This is the wrong way to use an ACID database. If you want to update a value, use `UPDATE table SET x = x + 1 WHERE x = old_value` - if the value has been updated by another transaction, your transaction will fail and you can retry. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: do not lock tables if ever possible because this can, well, lock up your system. To increment a value you can read and increment the value within **one** SQL statement. If you want to use multiple statements you can check that the old value still holds (`update table set field = new_value where field = old_value`) or use `select for update`.

Comment: Do not lock tables. Use transactions, which exist specifically for this problem. A transaction effectively locks only those row in a table that are affected by your operation.

Comment: The one and only time in my career I locked an entire table was to add a primary key to a table that had none. I won't go into *why* that table had no identifying column, but I locked the table because I added the primary key column as a nullable column, then populated it with data from a sequence in Oracle, *then* applied the primary key constraint. Outside of major table alterations like that, I would definitely not lock entire tables.

Answer (score 1):

Others have commented on this - I'll state it bluntly.

> Don't lock whole tables.

Web Applications are, by definition, multi-user, multi-threaded Beasts and each of those Users and each of those Threads will want to work with many rows in many tables all at "the same time".

Think of cars travelling on a motorway.

- Closing a single lane slows things down a *bit*.
  Traffic in the affected lane *waits*, other traffic continues to flow.
- Closing the *whole motorway* causes *chaos*.
  *Everything* stops.  Huge queues form that take *ages* to clear, even once the motorway is re-opened.

The same thing happens in a database.

- Using a Transaction slows *some* traffic down a *bit* (transactions should, of course, written to be temporally short).
- Locking a whole table "logjams" *anything* and *everything* that wants to use that table.  If that's a "core" table in your application?  Big Trouble.

Learn about Transactions and how to *read* data reliably within those Transactions.

And don't lock whole tables ever again.